# Overriding existing mapping in ExtJS 5.1.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, view, overriding

I am creating a Viewport class and it includes 3 items inside; a **Header** with 'container.Container' base class, a **Grid** with 'grid.Panel' and a **Form** with form.Panel.

The problem is ExtJS overrides the header i created and renders to 'Grid Panel'; as you will guess it contains a smaller 'header' inside panel and gives those errors:

```
[W] Overriding existing mapping: 'widget.header' From 'Ext.panel.Header' to 'Employee.view.MainHeader'. Is this intentional?
[W] Overriding existing mapping: 'widget.gridpanel' From 'Ext.grid.Panel' to 'Employee.view.GridPanel'. Is this intentional?
```

This is how it is look like!
[image: grid]
I have not define any alias to neither the Header class nor the Gridpanel. Only gave xtype property thats all. Why is that could be happen?

Thank you?

Here is Header:

```
Ext.define('Employee.view.MainHeader', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    xtype: 'header',
    requires: [
        'Ext.button.Button',
        'Ext.form.field.Text' 
    ],
    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'center'
    },
    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me, {
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                width: 600,
                padding: 5,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'image',
                    height: 95,
                    width: 95,
                    src: 'https://openclipart.org/image/2400px/svg_to_png/69109/Free-Culture-Logo-Orange.png'   
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'container',
                cls: 'search',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    width: 350
                }, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: 'Search',
                    handler: function () {
                        alert('this is the Search feature!');
                    }
                }]
            }]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    } 
});
```

and GridPanel:

```
Ext.define('Employee.view.GridPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    xtype: 'gridpanel',
    store: 'EmployeeStr',
    title: 'ORest Employee Table',
    viewConfig: {
        markDirty: false,
        stripeRows: false
    },
    initComponent: function () {
        var me = this;
        Ext.apply(me, {
            tools: [{
                type: 'refresh',
                tooltip: 'Refresh the DB',
                handler: function () {alert('Refresh click');}
            }],
            columns: [{
                xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                dataIndex: 'id',
                flex: 0,
                text: 'ID'
            }, {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'code',
                flex: 1,
                text: 'Code'
            }, {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'firstName',
                flex: 1,
                text: 'First Name'
            }, {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'lastName',
                flex: 1,
                text: 'Last Name'
            }, {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1,
                text: 'Email'
            }, {
                xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                dataIndex: 'active',
                flex: 0,
                text: 'Status'
            }],
            dockedItems: [{
                xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                store: 'EmployeeStr',
                dock: 'bottom',
                displayInfo: true
            }]
        });
        me.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not sure if it's a correct adjustment! But i have added `header: false` config inside GridPanel class. So now its gone...

Comment: well! but this config creates another error; because of header is false and title of grid panel is not displaying `The title text or config object for the Ext.panel.Title component. When a title is specified, the Ext.panel.Header will automatically be created and displayed unless header is set to false.` @ http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/api/Ext.grid.Panel.html#cfg-title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you overwrite via your xtype settings (gridpanel, header) the predefined aliases defined by ExtJS.

Take a look at the source code of e.g. ExtJS GridPanel:

```
...    
alias: ['widget.gridpanel', 'widget.grid']
...
```

The warning should be gone if you define other names for xtype which you should anyway in order to distinguish between your components and thos eprovided by ExtJS.

Comment: i have changed `xtype` definition of all views and it's working without any warning. Also i have changed  `header` config to `true` and the **title** displaying as well.